# Evolutionary motivation behind number of neurons in DCMMP

Tags: evolution, neuroanatomy

I'm studying neuro-anatomy right now and I was surprised to learn that there are only three neurons along the Dorsal Column Medial Lemniscal Pathway (DMLP) which relays mechanical sensations from the limbs to the brain. Is this the same across all mammals? Is there an evolutionary motivation behind having exactly three neurons, instead of 4 or 2?

Comment: The species you want to look at for this are giraffes and, to some extent, elephants.  [This article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17664045) is talking about information flow in the other direction (corticospinal tract) but it might have some insights into the sensory pathways.  I did not read it yet, though.